# Laravel - DB structure change - Is this a good practice or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, tinker

Hello how are you? I wanted to ask you who have more experience than me if what I want to do is a good or bad practice in Laravel.

I am making an ordering app and in my database I have that a product has a certain price (one more field in the product table). But then I realized that when the price of the product one day changes, the price will also change in an old order, that is, the old order will adopt the new price of the product at this moment and not on the date when the order was placed, thus generating an information problem.

For that, I decided to create a new table that has the temporary prices, that is, if the price changes, that a new row is created in the database with the price on a certain date, but that the price it had in another is recorded. date.

Now, my question is ... How can I bring the current price of a product to that new table that I am creating, without the user intervening ... that is, migrate all the prices of each product to that new table.
My idea was to create a function that goes through each product and that creates a new row in the prices table with the product id, the price and the current date. Once this function is created, run it through Tinker and that the user does not notice absolutely nothing, but that the system adopts the new price structure.

This is good?
Is it a good practice or is there a better way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO! This is one possible way to do it to have a table with the price history incl. start and end date of validity. To not overcomplicate the queries for showing the user his order history I would recommend you also to save the price of the product in the order. For example in the many-to-many mapping table between order and product, where you can also save the amount of the purchased products.

You could make a CLI command (e.g. `php artisan make:command InsertOrderPrices`) then to fill these fields for the old orders after you created them.

Comment: Great! I will try your advice, thank you very much Maxi , Greetings.